# autoit imagesearch transparency parameter not working

Tags: autoit

i need to use search transparent image on screen. i tried some librarys. but those are not working as my want.

help me. how i can done this enter code here

```
#include "ImageSearch2015.au3"
#include <Date.au3>

Global $x = 0
Global $y = 0

HotKeySet("{UP}","hey")
HotKeySet("{DOWN}","heyo")

Func hey()
    $balikcisaniye = _Date_Time_GetTickCount()
    $array = _ImageSearchArea("bul.bmp", 1, 0, 0, @DesktopWidth/2, @DesktopHeight/2, $x, $y, 2,0x000000)
    if($array = True) Then 
        $balikcisaniye1 = _Date_Time_GetTickCount()
        MouseMove($x,$y)
        MsgBox(1,"","Found." & $x & "-" & $y & " / " & $balikcisaniye1-$balikcisaniye)
    Else
        MsgBox(1,"","Not Found.")
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func heyo()
    exit
EndFunc

while 1
WEnd
```

the library used on this script : (KutayAltinoklu)

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/page/4/

Comment: Please post your question to forum thread you linked. Otherwise please describe more verbosely what exactly are you trying to accomplish, i.e. what do you mean by `image search` ?

Comment: Additionally describe what you mean by "but those are not working as my want". What is the error, what output are you expecting, what is the output of the program?

Comment: dear @JackWhite 
When I say "imagesearch" I mean:
a function to search png or bmp file on the screen
(tolerance and transparency can be added for each pixel)

Comment: dear @JensBaitinger
When I add a transparency parameter, the function always returns "false". Whereas it should not be like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Bug!

Ok, I tested it and found a bug in UDF.  It cannot work as it is.

- Open `ImageSearch2015.au3` (or whatever you renamed it to)
- find the line starting with `if $transparency <> 0` (line# 137 of unmodified `ImageSearch2015.au3`)
- replace that condition with `if IsString($transparency)`
  it should now work as described below

#### Usage

It appears that the UDF uses ImageSearch DLL from AutoHotkey. [This is its documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm).

If that is true then the linked UDF's documentation is wrong/incomplete.

Here is what AHK's documentation says:

> This option makes it easier to find a match by specifying one color within the image that will match any color on the screen. It is most commonly used to find PNG, GIF, and TIF files that have some transparent areas (however, icons do not need this option because their transparency is automatically supported). For GIF files, `TransWhite` might be most likely to work. For PNG and TIF files, `TransBlack` might be best. Otherwise, specify some other color name or RGB value

BMP does not support built-in transparent color but that should be fine - you just need to designate any one color as transparent - that color will be ignored

I've read the docs and UDF source and it seems that this is what should be passed as transparency parameter:

either:

- string `"TransBlack"` if transparent color is black (`000000`) or
- string `"TransWhite"`  if transparent color is white  (`FFFFFF`) or
- string `"Trans224466"` otherwise - where `224466` is string HEX of color designated as transparent

  - That is, if your color is stored as integer, you will need to do something like `"Trans" & hex(0x998877, 6)` where 0x998877 is the color

#### Example

For example if your image `bul.bmp` has a picture drawn upon background color `#808080` (50% grey). So if you call the function like this:

```
$array = _ImageSearchArea("bul.bmp", 1, 0, 0, @DesktopWidth/2, @DesktopHeight/2, $x, $y, 2, "Trans808080")
```

...all background (50% grey) pixels of `bul.bmp` should match any colors on screen, that is - those pixels will be ignored.

That is, if `bul.bmp` is just a solid 50% grey rectangle with no other color, the function will always match. If it has one non-gray pixel at any position, it will match if screen contains a pixel of that color, etc.

Comment: dear @jackwhite
first of all thank you for your reply. I read what he wrote and rearranged my code accordingly. new version of my code:

`$array = _ImageSearchArea("bul.png", 1, 0, 0, @DesktopWidth, @DesktopHeight, $x, $y, 2, "TransBlack")`

but still it doesn't work. I typed yellow "Word" on a paint file with a black background and searched for "bul.bmp". I drew small red dots on the black areas in paint. and again I got the error not found.I also tried this with the png file but got the same error.

Comment: also i tried "Trans000000" and "Trans0x000000". but still does'nt work :(

Comment: Ok, I tested it and found a bug in UDF. It cannot work as it is (possibly made for older autoit version?). Open `ImageSearch2015.au3` (or whatever you renamed it to), find the line starting with `if $transparency <> 0` (line 137 of unmodified `ImageSearch2015.au3`) and replace that condition with `if IsString($transparency)`. Corrected file here: https://pastebin.com/XEkM8iJ4

Comment: If that does not work or you don't understand what I mean, revert the edits, and try a  workaround: pass zero as tolerance parameter and pass the following as transparency parameter: `"2 *TransBlack"` (that is, a string containing: digit 'two', one spacebar, asterisk, no spaces after asterisk, word `TransBlack`) where `2` is tolerance and `TransBlack` is transparency specification as outlined in the above answer. Tolerance must be non-zero for this to work.

Comment: thank you so much my friend. I tried what it said but it still didn't work. I had another UDF on hand and what you said really worked when I tried it. I changed the line you mentioned to "isString ...." and put paint and a red dot in the background. then boom! worked !!! really thank you so much I was about to go crazy

Comment: I tested it (which is why I found the bug) and the linked version worked for me. Whatever, the important part is that you solved your issue. You are welcome.